# Process finished with exit code (0xC0000005)

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, char

I am getting the following error:

Process finished with exit code `-1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

I am trying to loop through each character in a char array and add to another char array, here is my code:

`c_data_ptr` below is a string of the following:

id,hotel_name,resort_name,destination_name
1,My Hotel,Resort,Destination

```
void get_collection_headers(char *c_data_ptr) {

    printf("[INFO] Getting headers for this collection.\n");

    // Set char array of char array for headers
    char headers[SYS_MXL_HEADERS][SYS_MXL_HEADER_NAME] = {"\0"};

    // Current working "header name"
    char *header_name;
    header_name = (char*)calloc(0,SYS_MXL_HEADER_NAME * sizeof(char) + 1);

    if(header_name != NULL) {
        // Iterate over the data to get the first line only
        for (char c = *c_data_ptr; c; c=*++c_data_ptr) {

            // Check for a newline
            if (c == '\n') {
                //free(header_name);
                printf("ENDOFLINE\n");
                break;
            }

            if(c != '\0') {
                printf("%c", c);
            }

            // Char = ,
            if (c == ',') {
                memset(header_name,0,SYS_MXL_HEADER_NAME * sizeof(char) + 1);
            } else {

                // Add character to header name
                strcat(header_name, &c);

                printf("-> HeaderName: %s\n", header_name);
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("[INFO] Failed to allocate memory.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to [read more about the `calloc` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc). You're not using it correctly.

Comment: Was it supposed to be `realloc(NULL, SYS_MXL_HEADER_NAME * sizeof(char) + 1);` but that also does not make much sense either.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am a newbie to C, trying to learn it and coming from PHP background :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Using `realloc` in that way kind of makes sense, since it's the same as a plain `malloc` call. I've seen it a couple of times like that, but it's mostly used when reallocating in a loop, and one initialize the pointer being reallocated to be a null pointer.

Comment: I am trying to reset the header_name variable.

Comment: Lastly, `strcat(header_name, &c)` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That's because `&c` is not a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated byte string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What should I use then?

Comment: With `= {"\0"};`, do you mean `= {'\0'};`? Please also note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude right, the last past of my comment points to the facts 1) lack of a loop 2) constant value for size. (is I guessed correctly, the multiplier is a MACRO definition)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help with this, I think I have fixed the issue, well I am not receiving the error anymore, can someone verify my code below?

```
HeaderStruct *get_collection_headers(char *c_data_ptr){

printf("[INFO] Getting headers for this collection.\n");

// Create a new struct
HeaderStruct* c_header_structs = malloc(SYS_MXL_HEADERS * sizeof *c_header_structs);

// Create a dynamic char array for headers
char ( *headers_ptr )[SYS_MXL_HEADER_NAME] = malloc( SYS_MXL_HEADERS * sizeof( char[SYS_MXL_HEADER_NAME] ) );

// Set the headers index
int headers_index = 0;

// Current working "header name"
char *header_name;

// Set the bytes for header name
size_t header_name_bytes = sizeof(char) * SYS_MXL_HEADER_NAME + 1;

// Allocate some memory
header_name = malloc(header_name_bytes);

// Check if allocation of memory was successful
if(header_name != NULL) {

    // Give some blank values
    memset(header_name, 0, header_name_bytes);

    // Iterate over the data to get the first line only
    int hi = 0;
    for (char c = *c_data_ptr; c; c = *++c_data_ptr) {

        // Check for a newline
        if (c == '\n') {

            // Add header_name to headers [position]
            strcpy(headers_ptr[headers_index],header_name);
            headers_index++;

            break;
        }

        // Char = ,
        if (c == ',') {

            // Add header_name to headers [position]
            strcpy(headers_ptr[headers_index],header_name);
            headers_index++;

            // Reset header name
            memset(header_name, 0, header_name_bytes);

            // Reset starting index
            hi = 0;

        } else {

            // Add character to header nam
            header_name[hi] = c;

            hi++;

        }

    }

    // Free the memory
    free(header_name);

    // Loop over each header
    printf("\nOur final headers are:\n\n");
    int j;
    for(j = 0;j < headers_index;j++){

        c_header_structs[j].position = j;
        c_header_structs[j].indexed = 0;
        strcpy(c_header_structs[j].header_name,headers_ptr[j]);

        printf("Header %i | Value: %s\n",j,headers_ptr[j]);

    }

    // Return
    return c_header_structs;

}

}
```

I am now using malloc and memset.